# Python - How one can vectorize two matrices twice with a dot product in a stochatic process?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vectorization, stochastic

I have a stochastic process with Mmax trajectories. For each trajectory, I have to take the dot product of two matrices, A and B.
With a loop, it works great

```
A=np.zeros((2,Mmax),dtype=np.complex64) 
B=np.zeros((2,2,Mmax),dtype=np.complex64)
C=np.zeros((2,Mmax),dtype=np.complex64) 
for m in range(Mmax):
    C[:,m]=B[:,:,m].dot(A[:,m])
```

(here are just 2x2 matrices to simplify it, when in reality they are much larger)
However, this loop is slow for a large number of trajectories. I want to optimize it by vectorizing it, and I have some problems when I try to implement it

```
B[:,:,:].dot(A[:,:])
```

It gives me the error 'shapes (2,2,10) and (2,10) not aligned: 10 (dim 2) != 2 (dim 0)', which makes sense. However, I would really need to vectorize this process, or at least optimize it as much as possible.

Is there any way to get this?

Comment: The example data is all zero, the result is all zero. You don't need any computation for that.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is your concern, there is a way to have that multiplication non-vectorised and yet extremely fast - usually even significantly faster than that. It needs numba though:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def mat_mul(A, B):

    n, Mmax = A.shape
    C = np.zeros((n, Mmax))
    for m in range(Mmax):
        for j in range(n):
            for i in range(n):
                C[j, m] += B[j, i, m]*A[i, m] 
    return C

Mmax = 100
A = np.ones((2, Mmax))
B = np.ones((2, 2, Mmax))
C = mat_mul(A, B)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually used numba before for other processes, and even tried to apply it here but my knowledge back when was quite limited. I'll try again with your implementation. Thank you :)

Comment: CHeck that the proper indices get "dotted", I was not entirely sure. Now I added the proper numba decorator by the way, thanks Michael for spotting that

Comment: Do you happen to know if I substitute the 'range' loop in Mmax for 'prange', will it parallelize the code and then also reduce the time cost if I have multiple cores?

Comment: That I do not know, I just know that decorator on a similar code cut the execution time by almost 100.

Answer (score 1):

Define sample arrays that aren't all zeros.  We want to verify values as well as shapes.

```
In [82]: m = 5
In [83]: A = np.arange(2*m).reshape(2,m)
In [84]: B = np.arange(2*2*m).reshape(2,2,m)
```

Your iteration:

```
In [85]: C = np.zeros((2,m))
In [86]: for i in range(m):
    ...:     C[:,i]=B[:,:,i].dot(A[:,i])
    ...: 
In [87]: C
Out[87]: 
array([[ 25.,  37.,  53.,  73.,  97.],
       [ 75., 107., 143., 183., 227.]])
```

It's fairly easy to express that in `einsum`:

```
In [88]: np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik',B,A)
Out[88]: 
array([[ 25,  37,  53,  73,  97],
       [ 75, 107, 143, 183, 227]])
```

`matmul/@` is a variation on `np.dot` that handles 'batches' nicely.  But the batch dimension has to be first (of 3).  Your batch dimension, `m`, is last, so we have do some transposing to get the same result:

```
In [90]: (np.matmul(B.transpose(2,0,1),A.transpose(1,0)[...,None])[...,0]).T
Out[90]: 
array([[ 25,  37,  53,  73,  97],
       [ 75, 107, 143, 183, 227]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic solution! This one does not require numba, so I'll check both of them and compare to see which one is faster for my case.